# SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: large object xxxxxxx does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, largeobject

I had a table with large object.
When I want to delete a row. I have an error: SQL Error [42704]:

```
ERROR: large object 123456 does not exist.
```

I checked in pg_largeobject and I didn't find a row with id = '123456'.

How can I delete an row which has a nonexistent object?

The trigger on the table is

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_filledreport BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON rep_reportjob
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lo_manage(filledreport);
```

Comment: Can you show the `DELETE` statement and the trigger definition?

Comment: And for example I have simple delete statement: delete from rep_reportjob rr where filledreport = 'xxxxxxx'

Comment: @GhertaNicolae when code is requested update the question instead of posting it as a comment. And here also post the Trigger Function `lo_manage(filledreport);` Also what is `filledreport`? It is very unusual to pass parameters to trigger functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

- temporarily disable the trigger:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE rep_reportjob DISABLE TRIGGER t_filledreport;
  DELETE ...;
  ALTER TABLE rep_reportjob ENABLE TRIGGER t_filledreport;
  ```
- As superuser, tempoarily set `session_replication_role` to `replica`:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  SET LOCAL session_replication_role = replica;
  DELETE ...;
  COMMIT;
  ```

Caution! With triggers disabled, you can easily introduce inconsistencies!